# How to spawn items in The Binding of Isaac without Afterbirth+?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

The same as the title. Wanted to test some synergies but you can't really do that without spawning in items or incredible luck

Answer (score 3):

If you mean by using the [Debug Console](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Debug_Console), that's only available in Afterbirth+ and Repentance.
So with the basic game I don't think you can, a part using some kind of mod.